# Bootstrap alert is only working one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, boo

i am working on a web app in which after submit it calls a ajax page.Now if email is already present then it will throw alert.For this purpose I am doing bootstrap alert.But its working for the first time.Please see this [bootply](http://bootply.com/94645),
When you press the add button then alert displays only first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.fadeOut()` implicitly sets `display: none;`, thus you'll have to revert that, for example by calling `.show()`.

```
$(".alert").show().delay(200).addClass("in").fadeOut(3500);
```

Comment: well where show() defined I didnt not get show() here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Comment: I was searching for show() http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ but could not find so I asked.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, duh, you're fading the alert out, so next time it shows it's invisible :

```
$(".alert").delay(200).addClass("in").fadeOut(3500);
                                      // ^^^ that's a fadeOut
```

change it to :

```
$(".alert").delay(200).addClass("in").fadeOut(3500, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('in').show();
});
```